# Push OO or xslt doc to google drive from django

Tags: django, google-docs, google-drive-api

I use [pod](http://appyframework.org/pod.html) to generate reports from django. A very smart solution, I enjoy it.

But pod solution required an Open Office (or LibreOffice) installation on client desktop (or server side).

To avoid Open Office software I will hope to send report to google drive as a new (or existing) doc from a django app (or python ...).

Someone would to share expertise with this kind of issue? Else, What would be the steps to publish a google doc from django app?

Answer (score 0):

If your Python app can produce a csv file, you can upload it to Google Docs using the Documents List API and convert it into a Spreadsheet:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#creating_or_uploading_spreadsheets

Many other file formats can be imported, please check the docs for more details.